# SKSpriteNode save to file

Tags: macos, cocoa, bitmap

This is my first question at this forum, so perhaps I am doing something wrong.
I am writing a program in SKSpriteKit that will open a bitmap file in a SKSpriteNode, modify the sprite node and then save the modified sprite node to a file.
So far I have been able to open the file en modify the sprite node by adding children to it, but I am not able to save to sprite node back to a bitmap file. Is it even possible? If so, can you please give an example how to do it.

The following code opens the bitmap file into a sprite node:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------
-(void)openImage
//---------------------------------------------------------------
{
    NSOpenPanel *openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

    if ([openDlg runModal] == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)
    {
        NSURL *url = [[openDlg URLs] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
        SKTexture *tex = [SKTexture textureWithImage:image];
        _image = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:tex];
        _image.name = @"image";
        _image.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
        _image.position = CGPointZero;
        [self addChild:_image];
    }
}
```

Only I cannot find a way to turn the sprite node in to NSImage or something else that I can write to a file.
I appreciate any help you can give me.